# Error using WASAPI with PortAudio on Win7

Tags: portaudio, libsndfile, wasapi

I'm trying to use PortAudio and libsndfile to play .wav files in exclusive mode on my Windows 7 machine, but I'm getting

> error number -9984 "Incompatible host API specific stream info" .

I've filled out the PaWasapiStreamInfo struct as follows:

```
struct PaWasapiStreamInfo wasapiInfo ;
wasapiInfo.size = sizeof(PaWasapiStreamInfo);
wasapiInfo.hostApiType = paWASAPI;
wasapiInfo.version = 1;
wasapiInfo.flags = paWinWasapiExclusive;   
wasapiInfo.channelMask = NULL;
wasapiInfo.hostProcessorOutput = NULL;
wasapiInfo.hostProcessorInput = NULL;
wasapiInfo.threadPriority = eThreadPriorityProAudio;
```

Then assigning the hostApiSpecificStreamInfo parameter and opening the stream via Pa_OpenStream as follows:

```
/* stereo or mono */
    out_param.channelCount = sfinfo.channels;
    out_param.sampleFormat = paInt16;
    out_param.suggestedLatency = _GetDeviceInfo(out_param.device)->defaultLowOutputLatency;
    out_param.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = (&wasapiInfo);

    err = Pa_OpenStream(&stream, NULL, &out_param, sfinfo.samplerate,
            paFramesPerBufferUnspecified, paClipOff,
            output_cb, file);
```

Have I missed a step?

Thanks,
Tyler

Answer (score 1):

The technique you used to run the stream in exclusive mode worked for me.  It may be the case that you're not opening a stream on a WASAPI device.  Depending on your system configuration you may have DirectSound and WMME devices as well.  The following code will verify whether the device referenced by index `deviceIndex`is a WASAPI device or not:

```
bool isWasapi = Pa_GetHostApiInfo(Pa_GetDeviceInfo(deviceIndex)->hostApi)->type == paWASAPI;
```

You also need to specify the same index in the out_param struct:

```
out_param.device = deviceIndex;
```

You did couple things I did not. In your example you tried to set the thread priority, but PortAudio documentation states that the following line:

```
wasapiInfo.threadPriority = eThreadPriorityProAudio;
```

will have no effect because you didn't not set the `paWinWasapiThreadPriority` bit in `wasapiInfo.flags`.  By the same rule it is unnecessary to explicitly set the other varaibles to null.  To fix this set `wasapiInfo.flags` as follows:

```
wasapiInfo.flags = (paWinWasapiExclusive|paWinWasapiThreadPriority)
```

This should enable exclusive mode and cause the `threadPriority` variable to take effect.